# Angular ngRoute don't work with Express 4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angularjs-ng-route

I try set up client side route with Angular and Express 4.
I worked with guide [ngView](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) and without Express that's good, but when Express routing is enable ngRoute don't work. How can I setup Express that it work with ngRoute?

A little bit of code:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/category/:catgegoryName', {
        templateUrl: 'category',
        controller: 'categoryController',
        controllerAs: 'category'
      })
      .when('/category/:catgegoryName/device/:deviceName', {
        templateUrl: 'device',
        controller: 'deviceController',
        controllerAs: 'device'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }
]);
```

Comment: How did you set up server side routing?

Comment: @dfsq something like this: router.get('/category/:catgegoryName', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('category');
});

Comment: Okay, make sure that you server responds with `index.html` to all requests (except static assets) .

Comment: @dfsq i'm not sure, but router.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

Comment: @dfsq when i clicked on link i received html by server side routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you configured HTML5 mode you don't need to replicated the same route structure on the Express side. Instead you need to make sure server *always* responds with landing page (usually `index.html`) where Angular app is configured and bootstraped.

So it will be that for say route `/category/something` server still responds with `index.html`. Then Angular will parse URL and understand that it need to inject template and controller corresponding to `.when('/category/:catgegoryName', {...})` route.

Comment: Yeah, that's looks good, but when  I click on the link my page freezes.